# on modal/popup i want to show text or doc file

Tags: angular

I am trying to show text or doc file on modal but it will not appear on modal.it will download directly is not appear in modal.Please suggest me about this.and thanks in advance.Below i sharing my code.

Html code.

```
<td *ngIf ="(i != current)" style="vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="color:green"></i><a class="txt"   style="color:white" (click)="open(content)" target="_blank">{{data.FileName.s}}</a></td>
<ng-template #content let-modal>
 <div class="modal-header">

 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
 <iframe  src="data.FileLink.s"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  </div> 
  </ng-template>
```

Comment: browser dont know how to handle different file formats in that case it download  and iframe may not support doc and text files. it supports only web pages.

Comment: @KesavanR Then how can i show?

Comment: you can try using pdf document which support most of browsers

Comment: try using a pdf viewer like https://www.npmjs.com/package/bn-ng-pdf-viewer

Comment: you can read content as text and display in text area. If the  file is text